# AngularJS - When creating a service where do you get the JSON data from?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

New to Angular,

so am I right in thinking when creating a service you request JSON data from a server someone else controls?

For e.g. If I wanted to create a Weather app where would I go to get the JSON data? Is there a common place to research etc?

Cheers

Comment: no there is no other common place to research api's than in your favorite search engine

Answer (score 1):

If the data is not yours (same domain), you need to query the API from the dataprovider from the server, unless the data provider has some JSONP implementation. This is because you can't do cross resource requests in the browser, so you have to do them server sided (e.g. PHP). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Edit: if however the server allows CORS you can do it in js as well. Most API's won't support it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Actually, you can if you set the origin or adjust the policy.

Comment: Have a look at CORS:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: @DavidHoelzer I did account for your own server right? And as far as I know you can't do it if the server doesn't allow it (which is close to never). So could you please be so kind to explain what I missed and I add it.

Comment: With CORS you do not do cross origin requests from the server. It is specifically designed to allow you to do it from the client side.  That's where your answer goes wrong; you state that, "you can't do cross resource requests in the browser."

Comment: @DavidHoelzer a the exception. Ok will add it!

Answer (score 0):

To use Weather API you can use this site. They provide nice documentation for consuming their api. openweathermap.org/current